# how to get request header before send request with webkit/webkit.NET?

Tags: c#, c++, webkit, webkit.net

i created project http-connection(with display) via webkit.

and i need to display HTTP request, response header also, but i can't find how to get header.

i'm now using webkit with C#, but i can change project to C++ if nesessary.

i tried WebMutableURLRequest.getALLHTTPHeaders(), but in webkit.net, it doesn't work with assembly error, and webkit, it needs IPropertyBag and i don't know what class implements it.

and i don't know how to use IPropertyBag or CFDictionaryPropertyBag.

so, the question is how to get request/response header fields and values with webkit?

important thing is get request header before send request.

Comment: Do you need the request header or the response header?  Your question mentions both.  Also, [what have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)?

Comment: Can you not use [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) for that? It does this out of the box with 0 programming needed.

Comment: i need both. and i tried getALLHTTPHeaders(), but in webkit.net, it doesn't work with assembly error, and webkit, it needs IPropertyBag and i don't know what class implements it. and i don't know how to use IPropertyBag or CFDictionaryPropertyBag.

Comment: it is not for debugging. i have to implement request header viewer/editor.

Comment: There's no way to get the response header without sending the request, because you don't *have* a response.

Comment: before request, i need show request header.
and modify some request header, and send request then show response header when create DOM Tree.